# Recording sales amount in datadog metrics

Tags: java, statsd, datadog

I'm trying to record my website sales $ amount in datadog. However I'm getting way more than the actual value.

I'm using java-dogstatsd client and spring. My application is running on 3 hosts. I recorded all metrics (using sendWebOrder method) but no luck.

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties({DataDogProperties.class})
@Component
public class DDMetrics {
@Autowired
DataDogProperties dataDogProperties;
@Autowired
private NonBlockingStatsDClient statsd;
private Map<TopicPartition,Long> lags = new HashMap<>();
@Bean
private NonBlockingStatsDClient initClient() {
    NonBlockingStatsDClient metricsClient = new NonBlockingStatsDClient(
            dataDogProperties.getServiceName(),
            dataDogProperties.getHostname(),
            dataDogProperties.getPort();
    return metricsClient;
}

public void sendWebOrder(WebOrder webOrder) {
    List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
    tags.add("transactionType:" + webOrder.getTransactionType());
    tags.add("dataSourceType:"      + webOrder.getDataSourceType()));
    statsd.count("amount_count", webOrder.getAmount(), String.join(",", tags));
    statsd.recordDistributionValue("amount_dist", webOrder.getAmount(), String.join(",", tags));
    statsd.recordHistogramValue("amount_hist", webOrder.getAmount(), String.join(",", tags));
    statsd.recordGaugeValue("amount_gauge", webOrder.getAmount(), String.join(",", tags));
    statsd.incrementCounter("weborder", String.join(",", tags));
}
```

I'm trying to generate a datadog toplist by transactiontype. I'm not getting the correct amount in any of the metrics (tried mainly count, gauge and histogram.sum). Here is my datadog config:

```
{
  "viz": "toplist",
  "requests": [
    {
      "q": "top(sum:projecta.webtransactions.amount_histogram.sum{$TransactionType} by {transactiontype}, 10, 'sum', 'desc')",
      "type": "area",
      "style": {
        "palette": "dog_classic",
        "type": "solid",
        "width": "normal"
      },
      "aggregator": "sum",
      "conditional_formats": []
    }
  ],
  "autoscale": true
}
```

What am I missing? Is this the correct way to record money value? Do I've to do any rollup in config?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which counter is getting too much value? the `amount_count` ?